# passing id of an image to another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

This might a little noobish but I don't know where to start with my problem. A friendly nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to have a gallery of material, the images of the materials are stored in a database, now i want to make the users click on a specific image of the material that they like, this would lead them to next page that would calculate the price.

So i guess my question is, how do i carry this variable of their choice to the next page from the gallery?

Any help greatly appreciated

btw this is my code for getting the images displayed from the database:

```
<?php

  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db ("imagez");

  $res=mysql_query("select * from imgz");

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {

    echo "<a href=\"page.php?id={$row['id']}\" />    
    <img src=\"{$row['img']}\>  </a>";

  }

?>
```

Comment: `<img src=\"{$row['img']}\>  </a>";` must be `<img src=\"{$row['img']}\">  </a>";` - see the difference?

Comment: wow, you are awesome man! thanks it works, just one last question if you dont mind, how do I +rep someone in here? =)

Comment: left of my answer, click the tick-mark under the V-arrow to accept my answer, to up vote, you need more rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hand over values to another page by...

**(1) QUERYSTRING (URL)**

```
page.php?do=show&id=5
```

create those by pulling the unique id of a record from your db and create a link:

```
echo "<a href=\"page.php?id={$row['id']}\" />{$row['name']}</a>";
```

assuming that your table `imgz` has the fields id, name.

in page.php, you get those variables with

```
$_GET['do']; $_GET['id'];
```

**pro**: quick & easy
**contra**: can be easily manipulated by evil users - they change the querystring and get your script to do weird things.

**(2) POST**

create a `<form method="post" action="page.php">`with a hidden field named `id` containing the 'id' you want to pass. Add a `<submit>`-button to send the data to page.php.

in page.php, you get those values by:

```
$_POST['id'];
```

**pro:** safe, because evil user can't fiddle with POST
**contra:** overhead

**(3) SESSION:**

call `session_start();` on top of every page, write your data into the session by...

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id; $_SESSION['do'] = "show";
```

these variables will be kept between pages, in page.php you can simply use `S_SESSION['id']` and have that value - if you called `session_start()`.

**pro:** easy and safe, PHP will do the work for you (e.g. handling cookies etc.)
**contra:** will put load on your webserver if traffic goes up on your site.

Comment: Thanks, what i should specify though is that i do understand how to pass a variable from one page to another, what i don't  get is how can i get the 'id' of the image to be placed in to a variable in the first place once the user clicks on an image? if that makes any sense? :S

Comment: Some awesome stuff, i have tried using this, it all works until i add images, thats how i've done it 'echo "<a href=\"page.php?id={$row['id']}\" />{$row['name']}     
  <img src=\"{$row['img']}\>  </a>";'  but now every link only links the id 1 and only shows 3 images instead of 4, any ideas why?

Comment: instead of the $row[name] being the link i would like to make the image itself be the link that would pass the id, but whenever i add the code for image, the links only pass id 1, now if i just use the code snippet without image it can pass all 4 of the id's (which is how many records are in the table), have you got any idea why is this happening?

Comment: @user2209644: no, please post your code, edit your question and add the new code to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set URL parameters, so when they click it, you would have a parameter like;

http://example.com/pricecheck.php?photoid=435

Then on the page you would do;

$photo = $_GET['photoid'];

Then you would have the ID of that photo on the page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the variable via URL, you can use cookie to store the variable and doing the calculation to check up.

```
<?php  
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("price", "$54", $expire);

echo $_COOKIE['price'];
?>
```

Now that variable `$price` would be available for each your webpages, and finally don't forget to clear the cookie `setcookie("hp","", $expire);